# JXTable listen to sort and sort a similar table the same way

Tags: java, swing, sorting, swingx, jxtable

I have a number of JXTables which all have the same columns (but different data). You can sort the data by clicking on one the header of one of the columns. What I want now, is that the other tables are sorted the same way when clicking on the header of one of the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a mediator class that references each `JTable`'s `RowSorter` and registers itself as a `RowSorterListener` with each sorter.  When a given sorter changes you could retrieve its current list of sort keys using `getSortKets()` and pass them to every other sorter using `setSortKeys(List<? extends SortKey>)`.

**Example**

First we define the mediator class:

```
public class SortMediator implements RowSorterListener {
  private final List<RowSorter> sorters;
  private boolean changing;

  public void addRowSorter(RowSorter sorter) {
    this.sorters.add(sorter);
  }

  public void sorterChanged(RowSorterEvent e) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Now we implement `sorterChanged(RowSorterEvent e)` to respond to a given sorter event:

```
  public void sorterChanged(RowSorterEvent e) {
    // The changing flag prevents an infinite loop after responding to the inital
    // sort event.
    if (!changing) {
      changing = true;

      RowSorter changedSorter = e.getSource();
      List<? extends SortKey> keys = changedSorter.getKeys();

      for (RowSorter sorter : sorters) {
        if (sorter != changedSorter) {
          // Install new sort keys, which will cause the sorter to re-sort.
          // The changing flag will prevent the mediator from reacting to this.
          sorter.setSortKeys(keys);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Problem is the table doesn't seem to have any rowsorters. Even the 'sortManager' is null. However, the sorting works when I click the column header.

Comment: I think that's because it is a JXTable. I thought the sorting was handled by the Table, but I'm not sure anymore now.

Comment: Ah sorry - Didn't notice it was JXTable.  If you're using JDK 1.6 I'd recommend moving to JTable which gives you more performant sorting.

Answer (score 0):

I would not do that, because it takes control away from the user: s/he may want to have the tables sorted differently, to compare different pieces of data.

Instead, add a "Sort By" option to your View menu. Changing this option will sort all tables, but then leave them alone unless the user wants to sort a specific table.

Comment: There are instances where it is important to keep two tables sorted in the same manner; for example I've used this approach when building a "diff" view consisting of a left and right JTable where the scroll bars and sort orders have to remain in sync.

Comment: Sure, there are times when this is useful. But most of the time it's a really bad idea from a user experience perspective. It violates the "principle of least astonishment."